# php how to manage multiple sessions in zend framework

Tags: php, session, zend-framework

I have a requirement in my project that i have to use two different sessions, one for admin and other for user. So i can open both account at a time in the same browser in different tabs.

Comment: This project is already configured, so i also don't know how it is managing the session.

Comment: I think its only admin who want to use user's section. Is there any role management section in your project ?

Comment: yes we are managing roles, admin has different role and user have different role

Comment: so why not assign all user's role to admin, to avoid this two session in same browser.